# In Python3/OS X, how to pass a string with apostrophe to a terminal command?

Tags: macos, python-3.x, echo, clipboard, pbcopy

I have a Python 3 application that should at some point put a string into the clipboard. I am using system commands `echo` and `pbcopy` and it works properly. However, when the string includes an apostrophe (and who knows, maybe other special characters), it exits with an error. Here is a code sample:

```
import os

my_text = "Peoples Land"
os.system("echo '%s' | pbcopy" % my_text)
```

It works ok. But if you correct the string to "People's Land", it returns this error:

```
sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

I guess I need to somehow encode the string before passing it to the shell commands, but I still don't know how. What is the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For apostrophes in a string:

- You can use `'%r'` instead of `'%s'`
- > ```
  > my_text = "People's Land" 
  > os.system("echo '%r' | pbcopy" % my_text)
  > ```

---

To get a shell-escaped version of the string:

- You can use `shlex.quote()`

  > ```
  > import os, shlex
  > my_text = "People's Land, \"xyz\", hello"
  > os.system("echo %s | pbcopy" % shlex.quote(my_text))
  > ```

Comment: I tried to implement this suggestion in my code, but I was having a hard time to figure out why it failed. I figured out that I still had to remove the single quotes just like you did, when using `shlex.quote()`. Now it works ok ;)

Answer (score 1):

This has more to do with shell escaping actually.

Try this in commandline:

```
echo 'People's Land'
```

and this

`echo 'People'\''s Land'`

In python something like this should work:

```
>>> import os
>>> my_text = "People'\\''s Land"
>>> os.system("echo '%s' > lol" % my_text)
```

Comment: Is there a python function that does that kind of escaping? I am dealing with values entered into a database, so it would be better to have the code doing that conversion.